# Cordova iOS ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview

Make a simple app with the following:
These are my steps detailed:

cd Desarrollo/Workspace_Xcode/
sudo cordova create MyApp com.mybusiness.app1 ExampleApp
cd MyApp
sudo cordova platform add ios
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
cd ..
sudo chown -R myuser MyApp

Open Xcode workspace, add in config.xml

Added info.plist

Then 
sudo cordova platform rm ios
sudo cordova platform add iOS

sudo cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.2.1 "Cordova WKWebView Engine"

Run the app, it shows the usual apache device ready, upload to appstore and validate is ok, my app rejected from apple:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com....

We have cli version 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova 5.1.1
Xcode 11.5
iOS 10.15.5 (catalina)
xcodebuild -showsdks
iOS SDKs:
iOS 13.5 -sdk iphoneos13.5
iOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - iOS 13.5 -sdk iphonesimulator13.5
macOS SDKs:
DriverKit 19.0 -sdk driverkit.macosx19.0
macOS 10.15 -sdk macosx10.15
tvOS SDKs:
tvOS 13.4 -sdk appletvos13.4
tvOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - tvOS 13.4 -sdk appletvsimulator13.4
watchOS SDKs:
watchOS 6.2 -sdk watchos6.2
watchOS Simulator SDKs:
Simulator - watchOS 6.2 -sdk watchsimulator6.2

Comment: where it is add in config.xml the following was done:
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

The only solutions i found was add plugin from latest cordova-iOS Code that is:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git
```

This is the only way to remove UIWebView references.
Do not add wkwebengine plugin, because it is not compile with new code.

Comment: It will add ios platform 6.1.0 dev

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my problem, now I can upload an app to App Store.

Comment: Is it possible to see your package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Cordova app using cordova ios@5.1.1. I was able to fix using following steps:

Install these plugins along with your other plugins:

1. "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0"
2. "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.1"
3. cordova plugin add https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
4. Remove cordova iOS platform
5. Add cordova iOS platform 5.1.1
6. Add this code in config.xml file inside "platform name="ios"> tag

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />

<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>

<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

It will fix the both splash screen stuck issue and apple warning issue.

Comment: followed these steps but still getting the apple warning :(